# IIS not connecting to remote databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, amazon-web-services, windows-server-2008

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
```

This is the error I am getting trying to visit my AWS deployed ASP MVC website. The connection string works with another shared host that I use, so I have a strong feeling that something within my AWS instance of SQL Server 2012 is blocking the connection.

I am new to AWS and IIS. Is there any sort of firewall that I need to be opening up?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding an outgoing MS SQL rule to my security group.